# How to know if current location is close to a marker? - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, alert, currentlocation

I have google map which contains multiple markers. I want to alert when current location becomes close to each of these markers. How can I do that? Could you pls provide me with an example? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Geofencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) (part of the [Google Play Location Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)) "lets your app setup geographic boundaries around specific locations and then receive notifications when the user enters or leaves those areas" and is compatible with API 8+ devices. The first link contains all of the code needed to set up Geofencing on a number of locations.

Comment: thanks for the link. But it seemed very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You must save your markers in one List, when LocationListener.onLocationChanged() will be called you will be able to compare your current location with markers location.

To get Market instance get it when add to map.

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
     .title("San Francisco")
     .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

To get LatLng.

```
marker.getPosition();
```

Comment: You not need mark, you need calculate distance from your point with X points